# how to dispatch param using x-init in Alpinejs

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

My Alpinejs component code is in an EventListener and I wish to use the magic $dispatch to pass a title string from outside the component. I can only achieve this using an onclick event but really need to do this on page load.

This is the code outside of the component used to pass in the title using @click. This works but it needs to be set when the page is loaded (in Alpinejs I believe this is x-init)

```
<div x-data>
  <button 
    @click="$dispatch('myparams', { title: 'The title' })"
    type="button" 
  >
    More info
  </button>
</div>
```

Using x-init does not work with the below

```
<div 
  x-data 
  x-init="() => $dispatch('myparams', {'title': 'Initialised'})"
// x-init="$dispatch('myparams', {'title': 'Initialised'})"
>
</div>
```

Here is my component with what I've tried to receive data from outside

```
<section 
  x-data="mypage"
  @myparams.window="title = $event.detail.title"
>
  <h2 x-text="title"></h2>
</section>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('mypage', () => ({
      title: '',
      init() {
        @myparams.window="title = $event.detail.title"
        console.log('I will get evaluated when initializing this component.')
      },
    }))
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this behavior is that you dispatch the `myparams` event before the initialization of listener for `myparams` event. So the first time no one is listening.

The future-proof solution is to use [`$nextTick`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick) so the dispatch fires after DOM updates.

```
<div x-data="initMyparams"></div>

<section x-data="mypage" @myparams.window="title = $event.detail.title">
  <h2 x-text="title"></h2>
</section>
```

Where we have a new `initMyparams` component using `$nextTick`:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('mypage', () => ({
        title: '',
        init() {
            console.log('I will get evaluated when initializing this component.')
        },
    })),

    Alpine.data('initMyparams', () => ({
        init() {
            this.$nextTick(() => this.$dispatch('myparams', { title: 'Initialised' }))
        },
    }))
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou Dauros. I'd never used $nextTick before now as only started using Alpine recently. I did make a slight mod as need to keep the addEventListener on its own. So ended with: <template x-data x-init="$nextTick(() => $dispatch('myparams', {title: 'Initialised title'}))"></template>. works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. Basically All I needed to do was include the component on the page BEFORE the onload (x-init) event.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).